# Is it possible to get a covariance matrix of fitted values for a GLM model in R?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, prediction, covariance

I would like to get a covariance matrix of fitted probabilities for a logistic regression model in R. I would like to do this because I want to find the variance of the difference between the two fitted probabilities ($\hat{p}_1 - \hat{p}_2$).

Here is my attempt:

```
x<-rnorm(10,10,10)
y<-x+rnorm(10,0,15)
z<-round(runif(10,0,1))

m1<-glm(z~x+y,family=binomial(link = "logit"))

predict(m1,newdata=data.frame(x=c(1,0),y=c(1,1)),se.fit=TRUE,vcov=TRUE,type="response")
```

This gives me the standard errors of the fitted probabilities but not the covariance.

I am aware of the delta method to find the distribution of a function of a normal distribution but I would really like to avoid using the delta method if possible because my actual code needs to be extremely flexible. It'll be difficult to implement the delta method properly in my actual situation.

Answer (score 2):

glm uses iterativly re-weighted least squares to fit GLMs.

The output provides a value called `weights`

To obtain the fisher information matrix you have $$\mathcal{I}(\mathbf\beta) = \mathbf{X}^\intercal\mathbf{W}\mathbf{X}$$ where $\mathbf{W}$ is the `weights` matrix.

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps - I want covariance on the fitted probabilities not on the $\beta$ coefficients.

Comment: It represents the first half of a solution, because the fitted probabilities are explicitly functions of $\beta$. Unfortunately, they are nonlinear functions, which is likely to drive you towards the Delta Method.  But if you were to be content with the covariance matrix of the *logits* of the probabilities (which are linear functions of $\beta$), you would practically be done at this point. (Benjamin, would you care to complete your answer by showing these additional steps?)